# Column looping through a user function and storing output in a newly created column (R)

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have some data that consists of an oscillatory-like pattern and would like to take some measurements of the peaks. I have several chunks of code and most of them work to do exactly what I want. The main issue I'm having is that I have no idea how to integrate them to work functionally together.

Essentially, I would like to use the freq function I've written on a dataframe so that it will loop through each column (a, b, and c) and give me the results of the function. Then I would like to store the output for each column in a new dataframe with the column names matching the source names.

I have read a lot of answers about looping through columns and creating new columns in a dataframe, which is how I've gotten to this point. Some of the individual pieces need a little tweaking but what I can't find anywhere is a good explanation of how I can put it all together. I have tried to no avail; I just can't see to get the order right.

(For reproducible data)

```
library(zoo)
count = 1:20
a = c(-0.802776, -0.748272, 0.187434, 1.23577, 1.00677, 0.874122, 0.232802, -0.279368, -1.57815, -1.76652, -0.958916, -0.316385, 0.831575, 1.19312, 1.45508, 0.848923, 0.257728, -0.318474, -1.14129, -1.42576)
b = c(-2.23512, -1.36572, -0.0357366, 0.925563, 1.53282, 0.171045, -0.438714, -1.38769, -0.696898, 1.37184, 2.01038, 2.6302, 2.53296, 1.8788, 0.100366, -1.34726, -1.4309, -1.37271, -0.750669, 0.100656)
c = c(0.749062, 0.0690315, -0.750494, -1.04069, -0.654432, 0.0186072, 0.710011, 0.920915, 1.13075, 0.227108, -0.195086, -0.68333, -0.607532, -0.485424, 0.495913, 0.655385, 0.468796, 0.274053, -0.906834 , 0.321526)
test = data.frame(count, a, b, c)
d = 20:40
```

This is the chunk of code I've written to go through any data I specify and identify local peaks, then calculate a series of things from the identified peaks. It works really well and there's no issue with the functionality of this (however, suggestions to make it better are welcome), just with putting it together with the rest.
 I would like to loop through columns of a dataframe (using a for loop in the next section to accomplish that) and get the result of the freq function for each column

```
freq = function(x, y, data, w=1, span = 0.05, ...) {
       require(zoo)
       n = length(y)
       y.smooth = loess(y ~ x, span = span)$fitted
       y.max = rollapply(zoo(y.smooth), 2*w+1, max, align = "center")
       delta = y.max - y.smooth[-c(1:w, n+1-1:w)]
       i.max = which(delta <= 0) + w #identifies peaks
       list(x = x[i.max], i = i.max, y.hat = y.smooth)
       dist = diff(i.max) #calculates distance between peaks
       instfreq = (25/dist) #calculates the rate of each peak occurence
       print(instfreq) #output I ultimately want
}

#example
freq(count, a, span = 0.5)
```

This is how I'm looping through columns in a specified dataframe. Also, I'm not sure what I've done but this ends up printing my output twice...(which I'd like to avoid).

```
for(i in test){
    output <- freq(test$count, y = i, span = 0.5)
    print(output)
}
```

This is probably the part giving me the biggest headache. This should add new columns to an existing dataframe. It works so far but I have yet to figure out how to integrate it into the stuff above. Also, I'd really like for it to store the output in a new dataframe, rather than the source dataframe.

For reference, here df = data, to.add = data to add to df, new.name = name of new col

Another thing I'd like is for the new.name to come from the source (to.add). For example if I tried to add d (from above) to the end of test, I'd like for the column name (new.name) to read d without having to specify it. This will be helpful when I'm looping through multiple columns and want to keep the source name from which the output was calculated.

```
add.col = function(df, to.add, new.name){
  if (nrow(df) < length(to.add)){ 
    df =  # pads rows if needed
  rbind(df, matrix(NA, length(to.add)-nrow(df), ncol(df),
  dimnames = list(NULL, names(df))))
  }
  length(to.add) = nrow(df) # pads with NA's
  df[, new.name] = to.add; # names new col whatever was placed in new.name arg
  return(head(df)) #shortened output so I can verify it worked 
               #when I was testing it for myself, this would 
               #need to be changed so that it adds the column 
               #to a dataframe and stores the results, which 
               #I believe would require I use print() and a store
               #like Results = print(df)
}
#example
addcol(test, d, "d") #would like the code to grab the name d just from the to.add                   
 #argument, without having to specify "d" as the new.name
```

Any help, suggestions, or refinements (to make it less clunky, more efficient, etc) would be greatly appreciated. 
I can get by with the for loop (if the duplications get fixed) as long as I can figure out how to store all the output together in one place. My actual data is in a similar format to the reproducible set above, it just has far more rows and columns (and will already be in a .csv dataframe rather than creating it from individual vectors).

I've been beating my head over this for a few days now and have gotten so far but just can't get it all the way.

Also, feel free to edit the title to help it get to the right people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first of all, the reason your function is printing the output twice is because essentially what happens is:

- instfreq gets calculated and returned
- **instfreq gets printed out**
- instfreq is getting assigned to output
- **output gets printed out again**

Furthermore, I suppose you don't want you function to try and calculate it for the count argument (which returns numeric(0)) so it would be best to run it only for the other columns.
Lastly, such simple for loops can easily be replaced by the apply function in r. Which brings the first part of your question to:

```
freq = function(x, y, data, w=1, span = 0.05, ...) {
  require(zoo)
  n = length(y)
  y.smooth = loess(y ~ x, span = span)$fitted
  y.max = rollapply(zoo(y.smooth), 2*w+1, max, align = "center")
  delta = y.max - y.smooth[-c(1:w, n+1-1:w)]
  i.max = which(delta <= 0) + w #identifies peaks
  list(x = x[i.max], i = i.max, y.hat = y.smooth)
  dist = diff(i.max) #calculates distance between peaks
  instfreq = (25/dist) #calculates the rate of each peak occurence
  return(instfreq) #output I ultimately want
}
output <- apply(test[,2:length(test[1,])],2, function(v) freq(test$count, y=v, span=0.5))
output
#       a        b        c 
#2.500000 3.571429 2.777778
```

the second part of your question wants to return the name of a variable to use it as the name of the new column. for this we can use deparse(substitute(variable)) so your function becomes:

```
add.col = function(df, to.add){
  new.name <- deparse(substitute(to.add))
  if (nrow(df) < length(to.add)){ 
    df =  # pads rows if needed
      rbind(df, matrix(NA, length(to.add)-nrow(df), ncol(df),
                       dimnames = list(NULL, names(df))))
  }
  length(to.add) = nrow(df) # pads with NA's
  df[, new.name] = to.add; # names new col whatever was placed in new.name arg
  return(df) 
}
#example
dnametest = 20:40
add.col(test, dnametest)
#   count         a          b          c dnametest
#1      1 -0.802776 -2.2351200  0.7490620        20
#2      2 -0.748272 -1.3657200  0.0690315        21
#etc.
```

this function will **not** override your original dataframe, so you simply need to assign it to a new dataframe:

```
newframe <- add.col(test, dnametest)
```

**EDIT adding a possibility to loop x amount of arrays:**

The first problem you'll have while trying to loop, is that you're working with arrays of different lengths. This makes it hard to work with dataframes so you'll have to work with lists. In this case it will be easier to write a new function which takes any amount of arrays, and loops them for you automatically. Because it's easier to catch and add the names in this function, I've readjusted your function add.col to take new.name again:

```
add.col = function(df, to.add, new.name){
  if (nrow(df) < length(to.add)){ 
    df =  # pads rows if needed
      rbind(df, matrix(NA, length(to.add)-nrow(df), ncol(df),
                       dimnames = list(NULL, names(df))))
  }
  length(to.add) = nrow(df) # pads with NA's
  df[, new.name] = to.add; 
  return((df)) 
}
```

then I can write a second function add.multicol like this:

```
#this function takes in an unspecfied number of arguments
add.multicol <- function(df, ...){
  #convert this number of arguments to a list
  to.add.cols <- list(...)
  #add the variable names to this list
  names(to.add.cols) <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
  #find number of columns to add
  number.cols.to.add <- length(to.add.cols)
  #loop add.col
  newframe <- df
  for(i in 1:number.cols.to.add){
    to.add.col <- array(unlist(to.add.cols[i]))
    to.add.col.name <- names(to.add.cols[i])
    newframe <- add.col(newframe,to.add.col,to.add.col.name)
  }
  return(newframe)
}
```

This will allow you to do whichever you want. Example:

```
dnametest <- 20:40
test1 <- 1:15
test2 <- 25:56
argumentsake <- seq(0,1,length=21)
#run function
newframe <- add.multicol(test,dnametest,test1,test2,argumentsake)
newframe
#   count         a          b          c dnametest test1 test2 argumentsake
#1      1 -0.802776 -2.2351200  0.7490620        20     1    25         0.00
#2      2 -0.748272 -1.3657200  0.0690315        21     2    26         0.05
#3      3  0.187434 -0.0357366 -0.7504940        22     3    27         0.10
#4      4  1.235770  0.9255630 -1.0406900        23     4    28         0.15
#5      5  1.006770  1.5328200 -0.6544320        24     5    29         0.20
#6      6  0.874122  0.1710450  0.0186072        25     6    30         0.25
#7      7  0.232802 -0.4387140  0.7100110        26     7    31         0.30
#8      8 -0.279368 -1.3876900  0.9209150        27     8    32         0.35
#9      9 -1.578150 -0.6968980  1.1307500        28     9    33         0.40
#10    10 -1.766520  1.3718400  0.2271080        29    10    34         0.45
#11    11 -0.958916  2.0103800 -0.1950860        30    11    35         0.50
#12    12 -0.316385  2.6302000 -0.6833300        31    12    36         0.55
#13    13  0.831575  2.5329600 -0.6075320        32    13    37         0.60
#14    14  1.193120  1.8788000 -0.4854240        33    14    38         0.65
#15    15  1.455080  0.1003660  0.4959130        34    15    39         0.70
#16    16  0.848923 -1.3472600  0.6553850        35    NA    40         0.75
#17    17  0.257728 -1.4309000  0.4687960        36    NA    41         0.80
#18    18 -0.318474 -1.3727100  0.2740530        37    NA    42         0.85
#19    19 -1.141290 -0.7506690 -0.9068340        38    NA    43         0.90
#20    20 -1.425760  0.1006560  0.3215260        39    NA    44         0.95
#21    NA        NA         NA         NA        40    NA    45         1.00
#22    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    46           NA
#23    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    47           NA
#24    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    48           NA
#25    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    49           NA
#26    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    50           NA
#27    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    51           NA
#28    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    52           NA
#29    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    53           NA
#30    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    54           NA
#31    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    55           NA
#32    NA        NA         NA         NA        NA    NA    56           NA
```

**EDIT 2: extending the loop to take in dataframes of any form as well**

now it becomes quite messy, you will also need to rename your output elements so they don't match any column names already present.

```
add.multicol <- function(df, ...){
  #convert this number of arguments to a list
  to.add.cols <- list(...)
  #find number of columns to add
  number.args <- length(to.add.cols)
  #number of elements per list entry
  hierarch.cols.to.add <- array(0,length(number.args))
  for(i in 1:number.args){
    #if this list element has only one name, treat it as an array, else treat it as a data frame
    if(is.null(names(to.add.cols[[i]]))){
      #get variable names from input of normal arrays
      names(to.add.cols[[i]]) <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[i+1]
      hierarch.cols.to.add[i] <- 1
    } else {
      #find the number of columns in the data frame
      number <- length(names(to.add.cols[[i]]))
      hierarch.cols.to.add[i] <- number
    }
  }
  #loop add.col
  newframe <- df
  for(i in 1:number.args){
    #if array
    if(hierarch.cols.to.add[i]==1){
      to.add.col <- array(unlist(to.add.cols[[i]]))
      to.add.col.name <- names(to.add.cols[[i]][1])
      newframe <- add.col(newframe,to.add.col,to.add.col.name)
    } else { #if data.frame
      #foreach column in the data frame
      for(j in 1:hierarch.cols.to.add[i]){
        #if only one element per column
        if(is.null(dim(to.add.cols[[i]]))){
          to.add.col <- to.add.cols[[i]][j]
        } else { #if multiple elements per column
          to.add.col <- to.add.cols[[i]][,j]
        }
        to.add.col.name <- names(to.add.cols[[i]])[j]
        newframe <- add.col(newframe,to.add.col,to.add.col.name)
      }
    }
  }
  return(newframe)
}
testdf <- data.frame(cbind(test1,test2))
dnametest <- 20:40
output <- apply(test[,2:length(test[1,])],2, function(v) freq(test$count, y=v, span=0.5))
#edit output names because we can't have a dataframe with the same name for multiple columns
names(output) <- c("output_a","output_b","output_c")
newframe <- test
#function now takes dataframes of single elements, normal data frames and single arrays
newframe <- add.multicol(newframe,output,dnametest,testdf)
#   count         a          b          c output_a output_b output_c dnametest test1 test2
#1      1 -0.802776 -2.2351200  0.7490620      2.5 3.571429 2.777778        20     0    25
#2      2 -0.748272 -1.3657200  0.0690315       NA       NA       NA        21     1    26
#3      3  0.187434 -0.0357366 -0.7504940       NA       NA       NA        22     2    27
#4      4  1.235770  0.9255630 -1.0406900       NA       NA       NA        23     3    28
#...
```

this is probably not the most efficient way, but it gets the job done

Comment: It *almost* completely works except that it doesn't like adding columns of different lengths to a new dataframe, so there must be some issue with my rbind argument in the add.col function. It works if I just try to add a single column at a time but gives an error when I try to use it with the loop:

new.frame = add.col(new.frame, output)
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , new.name, value = list(trace = c(2.5,  : 
  replacement element 1 has 12 rows, need 20

Comment: if it works by adding them one at a time, the error probably lies in the way you're looping, rather than the function itsself. The thing you ask is not a trivial task, so I've edited my answer to include the possibility to loop.

Comment: "Ok first of all, the reason your function is printing the output twice is because a function without an explicit return statement, returns the last value it calculated." <- that's false, a function return the last statement value, what is a problem with OP's function is the last statement use `print`, which print to the console (and hopefully return it, so the assignment works). `return` is only needed if you want to exit a function before it ends (in a if statement for example)

Comment: So this works perfectly for adding multiple specified columns to a dataframe but my ultimate goal is to be able to use `newframe = add.multicol(newframe, output)` and, right now, when I do that, it places the output from a, b, and c, into a single column rather than three separate columns each labeled "a", "b", "c". 

Is there a way to integrate this better with the output loop? Sorry for asking such highly specific questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your goal. What is the output argument in that case? the output from the freq function?

Comment: I've added another update so the add.multicol takes both single arrays and dataframes. But this becomes quite messy as you will see